# Meaning of «Ah! les Bazaine» in La chute / The Fall

Tags: meaning, french-language, albert-camus, the-fall

In Albert Camus's novel *La chute* / *The Fall*, the main character 
talks about his life to an unnamed listener. In the second chapter, he 
makes the following statement while talking about friends and relatives:

> Quant à ceux dont c’est la fonction de nous aimer, je veux dire les parents, les alliés (quelle expression !), c’est une autre chanson. Ils ont le mot qu’il faut, eux, mais c’est plutôt le mot qui fait balle ; ils téléphonent comme on tire à la carabine. Et ils visent juste. Ah ! les Bazaine !

Translation:

> As for those whose function is to love us, I mean parents, allies (what 
>   an expression!), that's a diffferent story [literally: song]. They 
>   always know the right words [literally: word], but they rather serve as 
>   bullets; they call like one fires a rifle. And they aim well. Ah! the 
>   Bazaines!

The Bazaines is a family with several well-known members, at least in the 19th century:

- [Pierre-Dominique Bazaine 
  (1786-1838)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pierre-Dominique_Bazaine), an engineer who worked in 
  Russia for many years,
- [Pierre-Dominique Bazaine (1809-1893), also known as Dominique Bazaine-Vasseur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adolphe_Bazaine-Vasseur), an engineer, son of the above,
- [François Achille Bazaine (1811-1888)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fran%C3%A7ois_Achille_Bazaine), an army officer, youngest son of Pierre-Dominique Bazaine (1786-1838),
- [Georges Albert Bazaine-Hayter (1843-1914)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Albert_Bazaine-Hayter), an army officer (and 
  general), son of Pierre-Dominique Bazaine (1809-1893).

However, it is not clear to me what the narrator in *La chute* has in mind when he says "Ah! les Bazaine!" in this context.

**NB**: Please note that "les Bazaine" is a correct plural form and not an error. When you refer to a family, you use the plural "les", but you don't modify the family name itself. Hence "les Bazaine", without adding an "s" to the family name. So I assume the narrator is not referring only to François Achille Bazaine, who was [sentenced to death for treason](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fran%C3%A7ois_Achille_Bazaine#Trial).

Answer (score 2):

Even though only [François Achille 
Bazaine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fran%C3%A7ois_Achille_Bazaine) 
was accused of treason (and sentenced for it), it appears that his 
family name became a synonym for treason. Bazaine surrendered an army 
of 180,000 to the Prussians in October 1870.

In [*Paris 
livré*](https://archive.org/details/parislivr00flougoog/page/n135/mode/2up?q=%22les+Bazaine%22), published in 1871, Gustave Flourens already used the phrase "les Bazaine":

> (...) ce gouvernement de traîtres dont il révélait chaque 
>   perfidie, combattant dans chacune de ses pages les Bazaine et les 
>   Trochu, (...).

These words are part of a chapter entitled "La trahison de Bazaine 
cachée aux Parisiens par Jules Favre" ("Bazaine's treason hidden from 
the Parisians by Jules Favre"); the text criticizes 
[Favre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jules_Favre), vice-president 
after the capitulation in the Franco-Prussian war, rather than Bazaine.

An unidentified author wrote in 
[*Sabaudia*](https://archive.org/details/sabaudiarevuehi00unkngoog/page/n316/mode/2up?q=%22les+Bazaine%22) in 1872,

> Ce Bazaine de l'époque (...) s'enfuit méprisé de tous. (...) En 
>   1870, l'Als[ace et] la Lorraine sont le fruit de cette trahison; 
>   (...). 
>   Mais les Bazaine sont rare, (...).

Translation:

> That Bazaine of those days (...) fled under general contempt. (...)
>   In 1870, Alsace and Lorraine are the results of this treason. (...)
>   But the Bazaines are rare, (...).

(The right side of the page was not scanned completely, which leads to 
gaps in the sentences.)

In [*Guerre de 
1870-1871*](https://archive.org/details/GuerreDe18701871Vol11?q=%22les+Bazaine%22), published in 1896, Alfred Duquet wrote,

> mais il y avait encore moyen de sortir du mortel guêpier où les 
>   Mac-Mahon et les Bazaine avaient jeté la France, (...)

Translation:

> but there was still a way to get out of the deadly wasp's nest into 
>   which the Mac-Mahons and the Bazaines had thrown France, (...)

Mac-Mahon refers to [Patrice de 
MacMahon (1808 – 1893)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patrice_de_MacMahon#War_and_the_Paris_Commune), French 
general and politician, who had suffered several military defeats in 
the Franco-Prussian war.

In [*Le général 
Bourbaki*](https://archive.org/details/legnralbourbaki00grangoog?q=%22les+Bazaine%22), published in 1898 (the year following [Bourbaki's](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles-Denis_Bourbaki) death), Léonce Grandin wrote,

> C'est elle [la guerre] qui é créé les plus grands homme de notre 
>   armée, les Turenne, les Condé, les Villars; c'est elle aussie qui a 
>   produit les profondes erreurs de nos souverains, les Soubise, les 
>   Contades; nous pourrions dire aussi les ... Bazaine.

Translation:

> It is she [the war; the word is feminine in French] who created our 
>   army's greatest men, the 
>   [Turennes](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henri_de_La_Tour_d%27Auvergne_(vicomte_de_Turenne)), the Condés [presumably [Louis V Joseph de Bourbon-Condé](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louis_V_Joseph_de_Bourbon-Cond%C3%A9)], the [Villars](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Claude-Louis-Hector_de_Villars); it is also 
>   she who produced the deep error of our monarchs, the Soubises 
>   [presumably [Benjamin de Rohan](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benjamin_de_Rohan)], the 
>   Contades [possibly [Érasme Gaspard de Contades](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89rasme_Gaspard_de_Contades)]; we might also say the ... Bazaines.

In [*La Laterne de 
Bruant*](https://archive.org/details/lalanternedebrua130unse/page/146/mode/2up?q=%22les+Bazaine%22), the singer [Aristide Bruant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aristide_Bruant) included the following words in one of his songs:

> Mais ... entendonds-nous: N'en faut plus
>   S'ils veulent jouer les Bazaine.

Translation:

> But ... let's agree: there's no need for them to play the Bazaines.

Unless the French believed in a family's collective guilt when one 
family member became guilty of treason or another crime, "les Bazaine" 
refers to "François Achille Bazaine and other people who would do 
something similar (or defend him)".